# Email alert limitation with unsupported objects

Tags: apex, email, email-alert

I'm trying to send an email notification to support agent when new email is received for a case. I'm using EmailMessage as source object for email alert.

And there's no supported EmailMessage object in email alerts.

In apex I'm trying to use a method `mail.setWhatId('EmailMessageId');` with email template to parse fields accordingly. According to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm) whatId accepts any of Account, Asset, Campaign, Case, Contract, Opportunity, Order, Product, Solution, Custom objects.

In my case I'm parsing EmailMessage and getting an error `Invalid entity type for whatId`. This is ridiculous - I can create email template with EmailMessage object to parse fields but can't create any alerts via interface or apex code.

Am I missing anything? Any workarounds?

Comment: Did you specify the targetObjectId?

Comment: @MartinLezer it's either `whatId` or `objectId`, the last works only with contact, lead or user.

Comment: From the documentation link you provided: "If you specify a contact for the targetObjectId field, you can specify an optional whatId as well". So you can only specify a whatId if you already set the targetObjectId.